# Scala type alias with type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, types, alias

Let the following type alias

```
class Container[T]
type MyInt = Container[Int]
```

Is it possible and how to declare a type parameter in a type alias, having tried

```
type MyInt2 = Container[T <: Int]    // error: ']' expected but '<:' found.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do:

```scala
type MyInt2[T <: Int] = Container[T]
```

As for other members (e.g. `def`), type member must declare type parameter in its declaration/signature (left), not in the body (right).